# Using Flow for styled-components Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, types, flowtype, styled-components

So I have been playing around with type systems in JavaScript and for the most part things are working however there is an issue with styled-components. I can't seem to find a good way to apply flow to the props of a styled-component. So far the only solution I see is:

```
export type ButtonPropTypes = ReactPropTypes & {
  styleType: 'safe' | 'info' | 'warning' | 'danger' | 'link',
  isPill: boolean,
  isThin: boolean,
};

export const ButtonStyled = styled.button`
  ${generateBaseStyles}
  ${hoverStyles}
  ${fillStyles}
  ${thinStyles}
  ${linkStyles}
`;

export const Button = (props: ButtonPropTypes) => <ButtonStyled {...props} />;
```

It seems pretty excessive that I have to create 2 component for every styled component.

I am hoping my google skills are just crap and I am missing something but is there a better way to do this other than multiple components per styled component?

Comment: There is this issue, but no helpful comments https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1349

Answer (score 8):

Yes! There is a better way. The trick is to declare the type of the component created by styled-components. You can do this by [casting](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/casting/) the result returned by `` styled.button`...` `` to the type of a React component that takes in your desired props. You can generate the type of a React component that takes in arbitrary props with `type mytype = React.ComponentType<MyProps>`.

```
// @flow
import styled from 'styled-components'
// Make sure you import with * to import the types too
import * as React from 'react'

// Mock function to use styleType
const makeStyles = ({styleType}) => ''

export type ButtonPropTypes = {
  styleType: 'safe' | 'info' | 'warning' | 'danger' | 'link',
  isPill: boolean,
  isThin: boolean,
};

export const ButtonStyled = (styled.button`
  ${makeStyles}
  ${({isPill}) => isPill ? 'display: block;' : ''}
  ${({isThin}) => isThin ? 'height: 10px;' : 'height: 100px;'}
`: React.ComponentType<ButtonPropTypes>) // Here's the cast

const CorrectUsage = <ButtonStyled styleType="safe" isPill isThin/>

const CausesError = <ButtonStyled styleType="oops" isPill isThin/> // error

const CausesError2 = <ButtonStyled styleType="safe" isPill="abc" isThin={123}/> // error
```

I've hosted the code on GitHub for local reproduction (since Flow's sandbox doesn't work with external dependencies): https://github.com/jameskraus/flow-example-of-styled-components-props

Comment: Awesome, you can also use:
`export const ButtonStyled: React.ComponentType<ButtonPropTypes> = ...`

Answer (score 6):

In addition to [James Kraus'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49568425/2553600) answer, if you're using `flow-typed` (and have installed the package for your version of `styled-components`) you can essentially:

```
import styled, {type ReactComponentStyled} from 'styled-components'

type Props = {
 color?: string
}

const Button: ReactComponentStyled<Props> = styled.button`
  color: ${({color}) => color || 'hotpink'};
`
```

Comment: I didn't know about that `import {type foo} from 'bar'` syntax! Also, this is a better answer imho.

Comment: It does have its caveats (https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1350), I ended up with a slightly hacky solution to be able to use `.extend`, `.attrs` without flow complaining

Comment: `There is no ReactComponentStyled export in styled-components`: was the export renamed the new 4.x.x version?

Comment: Could be @robinmetral, this was with `_v3.x.x`